# ASP.NET gridview refresh

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview which is empty when webpage is opened.

there are 2 fields on top, userid + password and a login button.

When the correct userid + password is entered and login button is pressed, the system searches on the database for records belonging to that user and are displayed on gridview mentioned above (via vb code)

So far so good, all works fine.

however when I click on any of the rows displayed on the gridview (to display it's details), the gridview goes back to the original state (when page was first opened). Because there is no query at the beginning, no records are shown again.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong ?
I would like for the records to stay on the grid obviously, not to refresh the griview everytime a row is selected.

here is the code I run when login button is pressed:

```
strSQL = "SELECT * from databasetable where username='" + txtusername.Text + "'"
SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = strSQL
SqlDataSource2.DataBind()
GridView.DataBind()
```

ADDED NEW INFO:
The following code runs when clicked on the row.
I assume the problem is here, however I am quite new at vb/aspnet so I don't know what's wrong.

```
Protected Sub OnRowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        e.Row.Attributes("onclick") =  page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(GridView, "Select$" & e.Row.RowIndex)
        e.Row.ToolTip = "Click to select this row."
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there code for the row click that you haven't given us? I don't see `GridView,DataSource = ???`

Comment: Is your TxtUsername blank during the  row click ?

Comment: txtusername is never blank. if it is blank a message pops up.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18160368/keeping-data-in-gridview-after-postback

Comment: @Invent-Animate, I have ammended my post, added some new code which runs when mouse hovers over the gridview and row gets clicked...I assume the problem might be here.

Comment: @iandayman, thanks, your link send me on the right path...still some work to be done to make it work correctly on my webpage, but that seems to be the problem I am having. thanks