# Select Command and Search command are not working properly in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

all my commands are working properly but the problem is 
after I execute my Search command then I click the select link button on my GridView, My Gridview is refreshing and select the first row in the grid view and not the one that I searched.. example: first I run the Index Page then the GridView get all the record from database(10 populated record) and show to the index.. (No Problem)
then I type the firstname of the user to search it then i click the search button then the it filtered and show to gridview again here's the image
[image]

then I click the "Select" link button from Gridview and this what happened

[image]

that's what happened .. I clicked the select link button on "marcy's record" then it refreshed and get the value of RASI's Record on the first row...

but when my click select without searching it worked just fine

here's my code for search button

```
 string strconn;


        strconn = "select * from User_TBL_DB where (Firstname like '%'+@search+'%' and Middlename like '%'+@search2+'%' and Lastname like '%'+@search3+'%')";
            SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand(strconn, conn);
            xp.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = firstname_search.Text;
            xp.Parameters.Add("@search2", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = middlename_search.Text;
            xp.Parameters.Add("@search3", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = lastname_search.Text;


            conn.Open();
            xp.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = xp;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "Name");

            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            conn.Close();
```

and here's my code for select link button on gridview

```
 row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
        firstname_tb.Text = (row.FindControl("lbl_Firstname") as Label).Text;
        middlename_tb.Text = (row.FindControl("lbl_Middlename") as Label).Text;
        lastname_tb.Text = (row.FindControl("lbl_Lastname") as Label).Text;
        age_tb.Text = (row.FindControl("lbl_Age") as Label).Text;
        id_tb.Text = (row.FindControl("lbl_ID") as Label).Text;
        string gender = (row.FindControl("lbl_Sex") as Label).Text;

        if (gender == "FEMALE")
        {
            female_rb.Checked = true;
            male_rb.Checked = false;
        }
        else
        {
            male_rb.Checked = true;
            female_rb.Checked = false;
        }
```

and here's my codes for ASP on Gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#3366CC" 
                    BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                        onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="581px" 
                        onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand"
                        onselectedindexchanging="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging">
                        <Columns>
                            <%--<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="Select_button" CommandArgument ='<%# Eval("ID") %>' CommandName="SelectRow" ForeColor="#8C4510" runat="server">Select</asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>--%>

                            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True"></asp:CommandField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Firstname" SortExpression="Firstname">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Firstname") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_Firstname" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Firstname") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Middlename" SortExpression="Middlename">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Middlename") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_Middlename" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Middlename") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Lastname" SortExpression="Lastname">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Lastname") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_Lastname" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Lastname") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Age" SortExpression="Age">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Age") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_Age" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Age") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sex" SortExpression="Sex">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Sex") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_Sex" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Sex") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_ID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>

                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#003399" Font-Bold="True" 
    ForeColor="#CCCCFF" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" 
    HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#003399" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#009999" Font-Bold="True" 
    ForeColor="#CCFF99" />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#EDF6F6" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#0D4AC4" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D6DFDF" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#002876" />

                    </asp:GridView>
```

i connect it to sqlDatasource1 and disconnect it and leave the code as is. I used Showselectbutton="true"

that's my Problem hope you can help me thank you very much

Comment: This will help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18160368/keeping-data-in-gridview-after-postback